# 'for' instead of because

Tags: prepositions

Do you think all of the conjunctions below are acceptable? I just feel that 'for' may not work. Thx!

Bullying is unacceptable    because   it is against the school rules.
                            as
                            since
                            for??

Comment: *For* is no longer in common use today in the sense of "because," other than in literary use. It's now only a preposition in general English writing.

Comment: It's still grammatical, though.

Comment: @Kris When did you decide it was no longer in common use, and whose permission did you get to abolish it for everyday purposes?

Comment: Thx for the input! I understand it now that ‘for’ is largely used as a preposition rather than a conjunction in modern day English. Thx!

Comment: @WS2 Whoa! Too fast! No homework done. "*For* conjunction **literary** Because; since" https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/for ; "d. In contrast, for (as conjunction) has declined virtually to extinction in the spoken language, as well as undergoing drastic reduction in the written language" https://www.nottingham.ac.uk/conference/fac-arts/english/icame-35/documents/icame35-book-of-abstracts.pdf See also: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/for ....

Comment: @Kris Just because something is called an "Oxford Dictionary" is no guarantee it has been compiled anywhere nearer Oxford than Yokohama. The OED conjunction sense 2a of *for* (Compare French *car*, German *denn*) indicates no hint of it being obsolete. Example *1883   Manch. Guard. 22 Oct. 5/3   This is no party question, for it touches us not as Liberals or Conservatives, but as citizens.* I frequently use it in that sort of context.

Comment: @WS2 You better not.

Answer (score -1):

'Because', 'as' and 'since' are conjunctions.

'For' is a preposition.

So we can make only the following sentences:

Bullying is unacceptable ***BECAUSE***  it is against the school rules.

Bullying is unacceptable ***AS*** it is against the school rules.

Bullying is unacceptable ***SINCE*** it is against the school rules.

Comment: And how about "Why is it unacceptable? For it's against school rules."